# Equivalent to Welch's t-test in GLS framework

Tags: r, mixed-model, t-test, lme4-nlme, generalized-least-squares

**How can Welch's t-test be expressed as a generalized least squares model?**

A standard independent samples t-test (where it is assumed that the samples being compared are drawn from populations with equal variance) can be expressed as follows:

$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i$$

where $Y$ is the outcome and $X$ is a binary variable corresponding to group membership. The significance test of $\beta_1$ will produce the same t statistic as the standard independent samples t-test. Thus, the two commands below produce the same statistics (with the same degrees of freedom):

```
t.test(extra~group, data = sleep, var.equal = TRUE)
lm(extra~group, data = sleep)
```

Because a Welch's t-test allows for unequal variances between the samples being compared, my guess is that it would be equivalent to a *generalized least squares* procedure. The question then is, what call to `gls` (if this indeed the correct way of conceptualizing the problem) would produce the same results (including degrees of freedom) as:

```
t.test(extra~group, data = sleep, var.equal = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an interesting question. One thing to note is that allowing unequal variances will only change the $t$-statistic if the groups are of unequal size. If the two groups are of equal size (i.e., $n_1=n_2=n$), then Welch's $t$-test (denoted $t_w$) and Student's $t$-test (denoted $t_s$) give the same test statistic, since
$$
t_w=
\frac{\bar{y}_1-\bar{y}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{s^2_2}{n_2}}}=
\frac{\bar{y}_1-\bar{y}_2}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1+s^2_2}{n}}}=
\frac{\bar{y}_1-\bar{y}_2}{\sqrt{(\frac{s^2_1+s^2_2}{2})(\frac{2}{n})}}=
t_s
$$
I point this out because the sleep study example you give in your post involves equal group sizes, which is why running your example returns the same $t$-statistic in all cases.

Anyway, to answer your question, this can be done in `nlme::gls()` by using the `weights` parameter combined with `nlme::varIdent()`. Below I generate some data with unequal group sizes and unequal variances, then show how to fit the models assuming or not assuming equal variance, using both t.test and a regression function (lm or gls):

```
# generate data with unequal group sizes and unequal variances
set.seed(497203)
dat <- data.frame(group=rep.int(c("A","B"), c(10,20)),
  y = rnorm(30, mean=rep.int(c(0,1), c(10,20)), sd=rep.int(c(1,2),c(10,20))))

# the t-statistic assuming equal variances
t.test(y ~ group, data = dat, var.equal = TRUE)
summary(lm(y ~ group, data = dat))

# the t-statistic not assuming equal variances
t.test(y ~ group, data = dat, var.equal = FALSE)
library(nlme)
summary(gls(y ~ group, data = dat, weights=varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group)))

# a hack to achieve the same thing in lmer
#    (lmerControl options are needed to prevent lmer from complaining
#    about too many levels of the grouping variable)
dat <- transform(dat,
                 obs=factor(1:nrow(dat)),
                 dummy=as.numeric(group=="B"))
library('lme4')
summary(lmer(y ~ group + (dummy-1|obs), data=dat,      
             control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",
                                 check.nobs.vs.nRE  = "ignore")))
```

You also asked about getting the same degrees of freedom. The degrees of freedom are based on the [Satterthwaite approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation), and `t.test` applies the approximation by default as that is part of the solution described by Welch. But `gls` does not do so. Theoretically this could be done, and I believe `PROC MIXED` in `SAS` will do so, so you should be able to reproduce the results exactly in `PROC MIXED`. Maybe (probably) there is some R package that will make it easy to get the Satterthwaite DFs for general regression models (with continuous predictors), but I don't know what it is.

**Update by @amoeba:** The Satterthwaite approximation is implemented as the default one in the `lmerTest` package, so to get $p$-value exactly matching Welch's t-test one can run:

```
library('lmerTest')
summary(lmer(y ~ group + (dummy-1|obs), data=dat,      
             control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore",
                                 check.nobs.vs.nRE  = "ignore")))
```

Comment: +1. There was a follow-up question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142685 asking how to do this in `lmer`. I searched around and found a hack by Ben Bolker allowing to do just that: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/214007/28666. I tried and it works, I get the same value of t-statistic! I took the liberty to edit it into your answer, but if you don't want it to be here, please feel free to roll back with my apologies.

Comment: Actually, if one loads `library('lmerTest')`, then `lmer` output will contain p-values based on the Satterthwaite approximation, and the p-value will exactly correspond to the Welch's test! Pretty neat. Do you want to update your answer accordingly?

Comment: The Satterthwaite df are implemented in the package emmeans. `contrast(emmeans(m2, specs="group"))` replicates the df and p-value, at least to what looks like rounding error, where m2 is the gls model in Jake Westfall's answer

Answer (score 4):

if m2 is the gls object from Jake Westfall's answer, then the Satterthwaite df and associated p-value are computed using contrast(emmeans(m2)) from the emmeans package. In Jake's example, the unadjusted and adjusted df are very similar, so the p-value and any interpretation is effectively the same. Here is an example where it matters (I use a smaller n and reverse the group with the larger variance).

```
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
set.seed(497203)
n1 <- 8
n2 <- 4
dat <- data.frame(group=rep.int(c("A","B"), c(n1,n2)),
  y = rnorm(n1+n2, mean=rep.int(c(0,1), c(n1,n2)), sd=rep.int(c(1,2),c(n1,n2))))

# the t-statistic assuming equal variances
t.student <- t.test(y ~ group, data = dat, var.equal = TRUE)
m1 <- lm(y ~ group, data = dat)

# the t-statistic not assuming equal variances
t.welch <- t.test(y ~ group, data = dat, var.equal = FALSE)
m2 <- gls(y ~ group, data = dat, 
          weights=varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group))

m2.contrast <- contrast(emmeans(m2, specs="group"))
```

Gathering the df, t, and p from each into a single table gives:

```
      method               df                 t                  p
1: Student t               10  -2.3012090076821 0.0441633525165716
2:        lm               10   2.3012090076821 0.0441633525165716
3:   Welch t 3.91598345952776 -1.87308830595972  0.135881711655436
4:       gls               10  1.87308831515667 0.0905471567272453
5:   emmeans  3.9158589862009 -1.87308831515667   0.13588402534431
```

Comment: I'd suggest a slight modification: `contrast(emmeans(m2, specs="group"), method = "pairwise")`. The default method is `"eff"`, which produces two contrasts for the two-level factor; `"pairwise"` will produce just one contrast, but the same *t* ratio and *P* value since the dimensionality is 1.

Comment: yes, agree! This would be about the only time I use method="pairwise" --- I tend to use "revpairwise" because I want the sign of the contrast to be non-reference minus reference.

Comment: Ok. Revpairwise would be consistent with my comment. The point was that eff produces two contrasts that are the same in absolute value.

Comment: this answer as written reads like a comment to the other answer but if reformulated to stand on its own it would be the better answer in my opinion