# Different variance-covariance matrices of random effects per fixed-effect group in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

Consider the following `lme4` model: `Y ~ X*Condition + (1+X|Trial)`.

Here `Trial` is nested in a binary `Condition`. This model calculates the variance of random intercept, variance of random slopes and the correlation of random intercepts and random slopes. **I would like to calculate all these values but separately for Condition A and Condition B.** How can I do that?

---

**Additional experimental details**

The experiment we conducted is a two-choice task where people have to choose the correct answer. There are two conditions in the task (condition A and B), one of which makes the task harder. All participants go through sets of trials for both condition A and condition B. All trials are coded in a single variable named *Trial* - A trials are named A1, A2, A3, and B trials B1, B2, B3... We want to predict Y (binomial variable) from X (continuous variable) while controlling for the random effects in different trials.

Comment: (A note for future readers: there was a long chain of comments here that is now deleted. It became obsolete after the answer was posted.)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142685/ (a simpler case).

Comment: And also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213591.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @amoeba and using @BenBolker's brief remark [here](https://github.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/blob/master/mixed_interface.rmd)

> Extensions such as allowing different residual variances or different variance-covariance matrices of random effects per (fixed-effect) group can be achieved, somewhat clunkily, by using the `dummy()` helper function to construct an indicator variable to multiply by individual levels of interest.

we got to the bottom of the problem.

The solution is following:

```
Y ~ X*Condition + 
    (X*Condition | Subject) + 
    (0 + dummy(Condition, "A") + X:dummy(Condition, "A") | Trial) + 
    (0 + dummy(Condition, "B") + X:dummy(Condition, "B") | Trial)
```

The `summary(model)` in random effects yields:

```
Groups  Name                        Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject (Intercept)                 0.89343  0.9452                    
         X                           0.11695  0.3420   -0.85            
         ConditionB                  0.66731  0.8169   -0.33  0.06      
         X:ConditionB                0.07391  0.2719    0.34 -0.05 -0.47
 Trial   dummy(Condition, "A")       0.63854  0.7991                    
         dummy(Condition, "A"):X     0.09372  0.3061   -0.76            
 Trial.1 dummy(Condition, "B")       0.88833  0.9425                    
         dummy(Condition, "B"):X     0.12175  0.3489   -0.60
```

which now makes perfect sense, because only correlations that can be calculated are between intercepts and slopes for a certain condition (because they are estimated for the same trials). Correlations between Conditions are senseless.

Furthermore, `coef(model)$Trial` now shows logical values:

```
      dummy(Condition, "A")   dummy(Condition, "A"):X    dummy(Condition, "B")   dummy(Condition, "B"):X      (Intercept)          X           ConditionB    X:ConditionB
A1                0.9198822                 0.0209849                        0                         0       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
A2               -1.3029020                 0.3894812                        0                         0       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
A3                1.1294702                -0.2475288                        0                         0       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
B1              0.000000000              0.0000000000               1.21725268              -0.305314643       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
B2              0.000000000              0.0000000000               0.88317976              -0.209529267       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
B3              0.000000000              0.0000000000               0.27859781              -0.065708851       2.703544   -0.9929765          -0.07102448        0.2415836
```

1. Fixed effects are the same for all trials
2. dummy(Condition, "A") intercepts and dummy(Condition, "A"):X slopes are calculated only for Condition A, in Condition B trials they are estimated to be 0, and vice versa.

**N.B.** When specifying random effects for this purpose, it is important to:

- specify random effects for different groups of trials independently, not under the same `|Trial`. If you don't do that, `lme4` will estimate random effects for all trials, not just for the given condition.
- include 0, so as to prevent `lme4` from including a general random intercept across all trials.