# How to interpret the random variables defined by dummy() function in lme4?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Consider the following lme4 model:

```
mod <- Y ~ X*Condition + (X*Condition|subject)

# Y = logit variable  
# X = continuous variable  
# Condition = values A and B, dummy coded; the design is repeated 
#             so all participants go through both Conditions  
# subject = random effects for different subjects 

summary(model)
Random effects:
 Groups  Name             Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject (Intercept)      0.85052  0.9222                    
         X                0.08427  0.2903   -1.00            
         ConditionB       0.54367  0.7373   -0.37  0.37      
         X:ConditionB     0.14812  0.3849    0.26 -0.26 -0.56
Number of obs: 39401, groups:  subject, 219

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.49686    0.06909   36.14  < 2e-16 ***
X                -1.03854    0.03812  -27.24  < 2e-16 ***
ConditionB       -0.19707    0.06382   -3.09  0.00202 ** 
X:ConditionB      0.22809    0.05356    4.26 2.06e-05 ***
```

In [Different variance-covariance matrices of random effects per fixed-effect group in lme4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322213/different-variance-covariance-matrices-of-random-effects-per-fixed-effect-group) we were discussing the usage of the `dummy()` function to model random effects.

I was researching the function, and was trying to mimic te results that I got with classic modelling notation. I tested the following models which, according to my logic, should yield the same results as the `mod`:

1. `mod1 <- glmer(Y ~ X*Condition + 
   (0 + dummy(Condition, "A") + X:dummy(Condition, "A") + 
   dummy(Condition, "B") + X:dummy(Condition, "B")|subject)`
2. `mod2 <- glmer(Y ~ X*Condition + 
   (1 + X + dummy(Condition, "B") + X:dummy(Condition, "B")|subject)`

---

`mod1` was not identical to `mod`
`summary(mod1)`

```
Random effects:
 Groups  Name                        Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject dummy(Condition, "A")        0.8508   0.9224                    
         dummy(Condition, "B")        0.8854   0.9409    0.69            
         dummy(Condition, "A"):X      0.1120   0.3347   -0.83 -0.73      
         X:dummy(Condition, "B")      0.1777   0.4215   -0.46 -0.64  0.75
Number of obs: 39401, groups:  subject, 219

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.49297    0.06911   36.07  < 2e-16 ***
X                -1.04807    0.04032  -25.99  < 2e-16 ***
ConditionB       -0.19657    0.06299   -3.12  0.00181 ** 
X:ConditionB      0.23894    0.05060    4.72 2.33e-06 ***
```

The random effects results are different. Why is
`Intercept != dummy(Condition, "A")`
`X != X:dummy(Condition, "A")`
`ConditionB != dummy(Condition, "B")`
`X:ConditionB != X: dummy(Condition, "B")`  ? What do the `dummy` variables mean?

---

`mod2` was equal to `mod`

```
Random effects:
 Groups  Name                        Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject (Intercept)                 0.85052  0.9222                    
         X                           0.08427  0.2903   -1.00            
         dummy(Condition, "B")       0.54367  0.7373   -0.37  0.37      
         X:dummy(Condition, "B")     0.14812  0.3849    0.26 -0.26 -0.56
Number of obs: 39401, groups:  subject, 219

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.49686    0.06909   36.14  < 2e-16 ***
X                -1.03854    0.03812  -27.24  < 2e-16 ***
ConditionB       -0.19707    0.06382   -3.09  0.00202 ** 
X:ConditionB      0.22809    0.05356    4.26 2.06e-05 ***
```

This means that `dummy(Condition, "B")` = `ConditionB` in `mod`. But what does then `dummy(Condition, "A")` in  `mod1` mean?

---

**Update 1, according to @amoeba's answer**

So, if I got this right, the imaginary data matrix would look like this:

```
    Intercept(X)    Intercept   ConditionBX ConditionB  dummyA(X)   dummyA  dummyB(X)   dummyB
S1  A       1           5           0           -2          1           5       0           0
S1  B       1           5           1           -2          0           0       1           3
S2  A       1           2           0           -1          1           2       0           0
S2  B       1           2           1           -1          0           0       1           1
```

In the first case it stands: $Y_1=Intercept*InterceptX+ConditionB*ConditionX$.
In the second case it stands: $Y_2=dummy_AX*dummy_A + dummy_BX*dummy_B$

Is this right?

Comment: As I explained elsewhere, this is the issue of categorical encoding. In X*Condition, Intercept (all 1s) is the value of intercept in A and ConditionB (which is 0 in A and 1 in B) is the difference of intercepts between A and B. In your mod1, one dummy (1 in A, 0 in B) is intercept in A and another dummy (1 in B, 0 in A) is intercept in B. The models are equivalent but they are coded differently.